# Access Internal AWS Web Server from internet via NAT

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat

I 'm trying to access one of my internal(local) webserver hostted on my aws vpc from outside. I have set up

1. Publicly accessible NAT instance
2. private web server instance which is reachable from NAT instance.

I do not want to use ELB i want to use iptables if possible i tried the normal prerouting nat rules but those didnt work

Can someone help me on the same.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Having an Instance in a private Subnet is meant to be for Instances without direct internet access. It is a security decision. If you want to access your Instance directly from the internet, then put it to a public Subnet, or Put it behind an ELB, or put it behind an other instance ( like a web front-end accessing the private web-backend.)
If you want this server being private and access it for maintenance reasons, the most secure way is to have a Bastion/Jumphost in the public subnet, so you can SSH/RDP into the Jumphost and from there access the private Instance.

Other option is to have an OPENVPN server in your VPC, so you can access all your resources via a VPN tunnel.

Whichever solution you are choosing, make everything as private as possible, open only the necessary ports and restrict the source IP range wherever it is possible. ( Giving RDP/SSH access only from your IP.) Even better to use VPN.